# Equal probability of random permutations

Tags: probability, permutation

For $n$ distinct elements $x_1, x_2, .., x_n$. If we generate a random permutation $\pi$ of length n (so of all elements), how to prove that for every $i$th element $\pi_i$ of it, the probability $P(\pi_i = x_m) = \frac{1}{n}$ for all  $x_m \in \{ x_1, x_2, .., x_n \}$. So in words: How to prove that for a random permutations of $n$ distinct elements with length $n$, that any element is equally likely to be at every position.

That this should be true seems very trivial to me, but I'm looking for a proof of it. It seems to me that this should be kind of the definition of a random permutation, but I couldn't find a source that formulated it in this way.

Comment: If you equate "random" with "uniformly distributed", this is a tautology. If instead "random" means "aleatory" this is not true.

Comment: for which case it is not true?

Comment: If "random permutation" means "a permutation drawn from a probability distribution on the set of permutations $\mathfrak S_n$", as in "random variable", there is no constraint on the distribution one can pick, from a Dirac mass to a Uniform, to anything else.

Comment: Hm, "by random" means to me that I have n! possible permutations and all are equally likely ...

Comment: Equally likely is another definition of uniformly distributed.

Comment: Oh ok thanks! So the problem is in my formulation. But if I mean a uniform distribution by "random" this statement is per definition true and therefore needs no proof?

Comment: The statement is true. However everything in maths that is true, is true per definition. Whether or not you need to prove it is extrinsic to this. To prove it, consider generating the permutation sequentially.

Comment: @Xi'an It's not quite a tautology. What needs to be proven is that $1/n$ of all the permutations fix a given point.  But that indeed is trivial.  The neatest demonstration (which generalizes nicely to any permutation group) perhaps is to observe that all permutations $\sigma$ for which $\sigma(1)=j$ are conjugate to all those for which $\sigma(1)=k$ via the transposition $(jk)$ and you're done.